# Sending SMS using C#

Tags: c#, .net, sms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.net sms sending libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12840069/net-sms-sending-libraries)

I am using .NET from last 3-4 days I got success sending e-mail using .NET now i want to send an SMS using .Net i have searched a lot but couldn't found anything.

Comment: read about AT Commands. or SMS gateways.

Comment: This has been asked (and answered) many times already, even on StackOverflow, check the related questions on the right. Please explain what's different about your situation?

Comment: The linked duplicate doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered using [Twillio](http://www.twilio.com/)?

Twillio is a telephony that exposes voice and sms services via a REST API. There is an C# implementation client for the API

You will be able to send and receive messages.

As for sending SMS nativity from C#, I don't believe this can be done.

**Update**

In the past I have had success with [TwilioSharp](https://github.com/jgable/TwilioSharp).

There are other .Net [libraries](http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries) to choose from, if TilioSharp does not work out.

Comment: no not yet How can i use it ??

Comment: i have set all the framework needed for sending sms but i dnt knw how to use my WIFI network for sending msg .. will someone help me ??

Comment: well I am from Pakistan and twillio is not providing its services in Pakistan so is there any way to do this ??

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge, sending SMS from .Net requires consuming webservice which has access to gateway to mobile nework(GSM, CDMA..). There are some service provider which provides API for .Net developers for sending SMS. There are some paid serivices also where you pay some fixed amount for certain no of SMSes. You may find some free service providers as well. Just google bro by searching with keywords "SMS API for .Net".

Here is an example:

http://www.cardboardfish.com/products/aggregatoroperator/httpsms_xmlsms_codeexamples.html

One more example:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19023/Sending-SMS-using-NET

Answer (score 1):

Much easier solution - send an email to the appropriate address based upon the service:

http://www.emailtextmessages.com

Comment: Very Well thanx for that